# Defining the value of variable after expansion

Tags: series-expansion

I have an initial equation defined as:

```
x = Subscript[a, 0] + (1 - r^2)/Sqrt[1 + r^2 - 2*r*Cos[\[Theta]]];
```

I want to taylor expand this after subbing in:

```
y=-r^2+2*r*Cos[\[Theta]]
```

I then want to plug it back into the initial equation like this:

```
1 - (r^2*Series[1/Sqrt[1 - y], {y, 0, 4}])
```

But with the original value of `y`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this; if you want even without touching anything manually but you need to transform some expressions. First, let's make a rule from your substitution:

```
rule = y -> -r^2 + 2*r*Cos[\[Theta]]
```

It reads as "y is replaced by ...". For the first substitution, this wouldn't help us because we need the other way around. Additionally, you have to substitute `-y` so we have to make some transformation on this rule:

- turn it around
- negate both sides

To turn it around, you can use `Reverse` which is easy. To negate it, you need to *thread a multiplication with -1 over the rule*. Let's see what we have then

```
Reverse[Thread[-1*rule, Rule]]
(* r^2 - 2 r Cos[θ] -> -y *)
```

OK, the rest is easy. Use the above replacement inside `Series` and the original one to transform it back

```
Normal[
  Series[x /. Reverse[Thread[-1*rule, Rule]], {y, 0, 4}]] /. rule
(* 1 - r^2 + a[0] + (1/2 - r^2/2) (-r^2 + 2 r Cos[θ]) - 
 3/8 (-1 + r^2) (-r^2 + 2 r Cos[θ])^2 - 
 5/16 (-1 + r^2) (-r^2 + 2 r Cos[θ])^3 - 
 35/128 (-1 + r^2) (-r^2 + 2 r Cos[θ])^4 *)
```

Btw, I used `a[0]` instead of your subscript, but that doesn't change the approach.

Comment: Dang, that is pretty fancy. Thank you for the fast and thorough reply. I would up vote your answer but I am pretty new here!

Comment: @user3838785 Don't worry. Give it some time and don't accept my answer just know. Wait a bit and see what others have to suggest. In the meantime, fill out your profile and give yourself a sensible name. Read the [FAQ] and look around..

Comment: I will do that. Do you know if you can get mathematica to output "powers" of the expansion?

Comment: @Jimmeny You have to explain this a bit. Let's say you have `Series[Exp[z], {z, 0, 10}]`, what exactly do you want?

Comment: I am hoping that I can organize these coefficients into a sum of Legendre polynomials. They would look like this:

Sum([(2*l*1)*r^l*legendreP[l,Cos[theta]])

Comment: @Jimmeny But why don't you use `Table` instead of `Series` and create the powers yourself? Feel free to join our [chat] and we can discuss this.

Comment: Test: Does this work? Join me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19416/test-for-michael-e2-and-halirutan)

Comment: Hello, sorry that it took so long for me to reply. I can't join chat until I have accumulated 21 points. I keep looking for any way to reply to you guys but it doesn't look like that is possible.

Comment: @Jimmeny Surprise, you have 26 rep now.

Comment: I managed to join the chat!